# Running svn2git in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, svn2git

I'm trying to run svn2git in a Jenkins job to regularly sync up a Git repository with its SVN directory on a local server.

The job fails and is outputting the following message

```
C:\GitDirectory>svn2git --rebase 
command failed:
2>&1 git svn fetch
Error validating server certificate for 'https://machinename:8443':
 - The certificate is not issued by a trusted authority. Use the fingerprint to validate the certificate manually!
Certificate information:
 - Hostname: machinename
 - Valid: from Nov 19 09:07:49 2008 GMT until Nov 17 09:07:49 2018 GMT
 - Issuer: machinename
 - Fingerprint: 53:ba:1d:75:fd:0c:cd:7e:87:24:93:ba:28:32:11:2c:a9:8e:a6:b7
Certificate problem.
(R)eject, accept (t)emporarily or accept (p)ermanently? RA layer request failed: PROPFIND request failed on '/svn/directory': PROPFIND of '/svn/directory': Server certificate verification failed: issuer is not trusted (https://machinename:8443) at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/Git/SVN.pm line 148
```

Jenkins is running in Windows on a local admin user account.

I've used this same account to run svn2git --rebase through a command prompt and permanently accepted the certificate.

Subsequent svn2git --rebase in the command prompt does not raise this message, however I'm still receiving the message when trying to run svn2git via a Jenkins job.

Any ideas on how to get Jenkins to accept this certificate permanently?

Answer (score 1):

That's because `svn2git` cannot handle the scenario that the certificate has not been accepted in your sever. Either install that certificate in your server or use [svn2gitnet](https://github.com/mazong1123/svn2gitnet), which can handle the certificate issue correctly.